# LINQ Expression - Returning a UserID based on the Name Specified in a LinkLabel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, lambda

Please, I am trying to access my database to get access to a user id. But when i try accessing, what gets returned is 0. Initially, i had issues figuring out how to change this SQL statement (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE firstname = 'Godymn') to LINQ. But i later found that i could use :

var result = users.Where(x=>x.firstname == "Godymn").Select(x=>x.userid);

So far, when i tried to use the query in my code, it returns a 0. But what i need is to return the user id based on the name specified in the linkLabel. I have not been able to figure out why its not working.

Will appreciate any help.

Here is my code

```
private int Chk()
{            
    string link = linkLabelPartner.Text;
    var result = (dynamic)null;
    using (DbModel db = new DbModel())
    {
        result = db.users.Where(x => x.firstname == link).Select(x => x.user_id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return result;        
}
```

Here is the button i used to check the content of what got returned.

```
private void btnTey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int test = Chk();
    MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `UserId` is an int? I think `FirstOrDefault()` is just returning the default value (0) because there were no matches on the `Where()`. Try debugging your code to see if there is even anything to select

Comment: Also, compare `firstname` with case insensitive like using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. May be your input and DB value doesnt match.

Comment: you can change `result = db.users.Where(x => x.firstname == link).Select(x => x.user_id).FirstOrDefault();` for `result = db.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.firstname == link).user_id;` too :)

Comment: Try your `Where` clause like.. `Where(x => String.Equals(x.firstname, link,                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select...`

Comment: Are you certain that `linkLabelPartner.Text` contains _only_ the first name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, I was able to fix the bug. The problem was with the linkLabelPartner.Text as  Chris Dunaway rightly said. As soon as he mentioned if the linklabel contains only firstname, I just knew that was the missing piece. This holds firstname and lastname and I only accounted for just firstname. Hence the value returned remains at 0. So, all I had to do was to concatenate both firstname and lastname which solved the issue. So, yeah the query I used initially was right.

Here is the code

```
    private int Chk()
    {
        string link = linkLabelPartner.Text;
        var result = (dynamic)null;
        using (DbModel db = new DbModel ())
        {
            result = db.users.Where(x => x.lastname + " " + x.firstname == link ).Select(x => x.users).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return result;
    }     

    private void btnTey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int test = Chk();
        MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
    }
```

Many thanks everyone for your suggestions, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon Godymn.

Here are some possible scenarios:

1 - The user name Godymn does not exist in the database
2 - The user_id is 0.

Try checking this 2 scenarios.

After that, you could change your approach to a more "debug friendly" level.

`var result = db.users.First(f => f.firstname == link);`

Then, check if `result` is null. If it is null, the name was not found in the database.
If it is not null, check if the result is 0.

Why this approach: This way, you can tell if the problem is when you are searching for the user or when you are binding the value of Id.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, i'm sory, but first of all i'll try this:

```
var foo = db.users.Select(x => x).ToList();
```

then you can investigate your result like this
i suppose you try get wrong data (or wrong structure)
when i stuck i do this:
[image]

Or maybe you can attach your structure of object?